# How to properly save user profile picture blob in React.Js so it can be used/loaded/displayed across multiple components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, local-storage

I am currently having problems, figuring out how to properly save user profile Images.

So my app has 3 main "components".

- Sidebar with navigation links and Profile picture
- The page alone (In this case its a user profile page)
- The UserSession context which stores curently logged in user.

So in short, I am creating a copy of Twitter, the user can create profile, post posts etc...
The user has the option to upload and cropp their profile picture.
The profile picture gets shown on the Sidebar which is rendered on all pages expect /register and /login pages.

My problem comes with updating the profile picture, when the user uploads new profile picture, the profile picture gets correctly updated and shown on the sidebar, however when the user manualy reloads the page (by pressing F5) the profile picture reverts back the previous one before the profile picture was updated.

- I have tried fetching the profile image on page reload using useEffect(), that however didn't fix anything and instead the image got rendered as "null"
- I tried to save the data of the image as base64 in localStorage - didn't work
- I tried to wait with setTimeout - didn't work
- I tried creating seperate server and fetching the images from that - didn't work

This is my UserSession.tsx:

```
 import { createContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
    import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
    
    export interface LoginData {
        token: string; 
        user_id: string;
        username: string;
        first_name: string;
        last_name: string;
        profile_picture: string;
    }
    
    interface IUserSessionContext {
        isLoggedIn: boolean;
        username: string;
        profilePicture: string | null,
        login: (data: LoginData) => void;
        logout: () => void;
        userId: string,
        token: string,
        setProfilePicture: any
    
    }
    
    const UserSessionContext = createContext<IUserSessionContext>({
        isLoggedIn: false,
        username: '',
        profilePicture: '',
        login: () => {},
        logout: () => {},
        userId: '',
        token: '',
        setProfilePicture: () => {}
    });
    
    const UserSessionProvider = () => {
        const [username, setUsername] = useState<string>("");
        const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState<boolean>(false);
        const [userId, setUserId] = useState<string>("");
        const [profilePicture, setProfilePicture] = useState<string | null>(null);
        const [token, setToken] = useState<string>("");
    
        const router = useRouter();
    
        useEffect(() => {
    
            const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
            const storageUserData = localStorage.getItem('userData')
    
            if(token && storageUserData){
                const userData: LoginData = JSON.parse(storageUserData);
    
                login(userData);
    
            }
           
        }, []);
        
        const fetchProfilePicture = async(profilePicture: string) => {
    
            const url = `http://localhost:8888/api/user/uploads/users/${profilePicture}`
            const response = await fetch(url, {
                method: 'GET'
            });
    
            if (response.ok) {
                const blob = await response.blob();
                const objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                setProfilePicture(objectUrl);
                localStorage.setItem('profileImage', objectUrl);
            }            
        }
    
        const login = async (data: LoginData) => {
    
            localStorage.setItem('token', data.token);
            localStorage.setItem('userData', JSON.stringify(data));
            localStorage.setItem('userID', data.user_id);
    
            setUsername(data.username);
            setUserId(data.user_id);
            setProfilePicture(data.profile_picture);
            setToken(data.token);
            fetchProfilePicture(data.profile_picture);
    
            setIsLoggedIn(true);
    
        };
      
        const logout = () => {
            localStorage.removeItem('token');
            localStorage.removeItem('userData');
            localStorage.removeItem('userID');
            localStorage.removeItem('profileImage');
    
            setUsername("");
            setUserId("");
            setProfilePicture(null);
            setToken("");
            setIsLoggedIn(false);
    
            router.push("/login");
    
        }
        
        return { username, isLoggedIn, login, logout, userId, profilePicture, token, setProfilePicture }
    };
    
    export { UserSessionProvider, UserSessionContext  };
```

This is my SideBar.tsx:

```
    /* eslint-disable @next/next/no-img-element */
import Link from 'next/link'
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import styles from '../styles/PageHeader.module.css'
import { UserSessionContext } from '@/components/context/UserSession'


function UserSideBar() {
    const userSessionData = useContext(UserSessionContext);

    return (
        <>
            <div className={styles.UserSideBar}>
                <div className={styles.UserImage}>
                    <img className={styles.SideBarUserImage} src={`${localStorage.getItem('profileImage')}`} width="512" height="512" alt='User profile image'/>
                </div>
                ... some navigation links ...
                </div>
            </div>
        </>

    )
}

export default UserSideBar
```

And this is my UploadNewProfilePicture function that crops selected are from an image, sends it to the backend, receives data from the backend(the name of the saved image) and saves it.

```
    const updateProfilePicture = async () => {
    const cropper = cropperRef.current?.cropper;
    const canvas = cropper.getCroppedCanvas();
    
    if(canvas == null){
        alert("Empty area in image cropper.")
        return
    }
  
    canvas.toBlob((imageBlob: any) => {
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("croppedImage", imageBlob);
        localStorage.setItem('profileImage', URL.createObjectURL(imageBlob));

        fetch("http://localhost:8888/api/user/profile/newProfileImage", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Authorization": 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token')
            },
            body: formData,
            
        })
        .then(response => {
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
            }

            return response.json();
        })
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data)
            const storageUserData: any = localStorage.getItem('userData')
            let userData: LoginData = JSON.parse(storageUserData);
            userData.profile_picture = data.profile_picture;
            localStorage.setItem('userData', JSON.stringify(userData));

            const objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(imageBlob);
            setUserProfilePicture(objectUrl)
            userSessionData.setProfilePicture(objectUrl);
            localStorage.setItem('profileImage', objectUrl);

        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('There was an error!', error);
        });
    });
}
```

And this is my _app.tsx:

```
    import { UserSessionContext, UserSessionProvider } from '@/components/context/UserSession'
import PageHeader from '@/components/PageHeader'
import UserSideBar from '@/components/UserSideBar'
import '@/styles/globals.css'
import Link from 'next/link'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import Script from 'next/script'
import { useContext, useEffect } from 'react'
import styles from '../styles/404.module.css'

type AppProps = {
  Component: React.ComponentType<any>,
  pageProps: any
}

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  const router = useRouter();

  const pageToRender = () => {
    if (router.pathname === '/login' || router.pathname === '/register') {
        return <Component {...pageProps} />;
    }
  
    if (!isLoggedIn) {
        return (
            <div className={styles.NotFound}>
                <h1>You must sign in to view this content</h1>
                <Link href="/login">Sign in</Link>
            </div>
        );
    }
  
    return (
        <>
            <UserSideBar />
            <div className="pageContent">
                <Component {...pageProps} />
            </div>
        </>
    );
  };

  const { username, isLoggedIn, login, logout, userId, profilePicture, token, setProfilePicture } = UserSessionProvider();

  return (
    <UserSessionContext.Provider value={{ username, isLoggedIn, login, logout, userId, profilePicture, token, setProfilePicture }}>

      <Script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a2c399c19b.js"></Script>
      <PageHeader />
      {pageToRender()}
    </UserSessionContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

Comment: Can you confirm that the image is saved and downloaded correctly? Perhaps server returns same file?

Comment: Yes, the picture is saved and returned corectly, backend is not the problem

Comment: Does the image url change everytime you upload? If it doesn't perhaps the browser cached the image?

Comment: The image url changes and saves into the localStorage, if I change sites by clicking on the buttons (Links to other pages) the profileImage stays the same,    when I reload the page manualy the image url changes back to the previous one, even the the localStorage gets rewriten to the previous one

Comment: What happens if you clear localStorage?

Comment: Nothing, the new picture gets saved into the localStorage, but the previous one still gets shown when the page reloads and the localStorage retains the previous values.

Comment: I think at least one thing you told me must false. Either the image isn't saved on backend, or it's cached by browser, or it's cached by you in localStorage. There is no other way to persist the previous image, right?

Comment: If the reload of the page download previous image, it has to be backend that servers wrong data or you download, idk wrong user data. Can you show your api calls with results before and after you save new image?